# Serve assets before other routes

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am developing a web app using Node.js, Express and AngularJS.

I am serving my front-end JavaScript from the `public` folder, so e.g. that `HTTP GET /lib/angular/angular.min.js` would presumably return the AngularJS JavaScript.

However, as I want all requests to get handled by the Angular router in the browser, I have a catch-all route defined as follows:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) { res.send('template.jade'); });
```

The **problem** is that this route overrides the static asset routing, in which case it *always* run, even when a static asset is requested.

Is there a way to tell Express to process static assets before the custom routes propagate? Are there perhaps any other clever ways of avoiding this issue?

The Express configuration is as follows:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  var ExpressConfig, crypto, express, path, pkg;
  crypto = require('crypto');
  express = require('express');
  path = require('path');
  pkg = require('../package');

  ExpressConfig = (function() {
    function ExpressConfig() {}

    ExpressConfig.prototype.configure = function(ENV) {
      var APP_ROOT, app;
      APP_ROOT = path.join(__dirname, '../');
      app = express();
      app.set('port', pkg.config.port);
      app.set('views', APP_ROOT + 'webapp');
      app.set('view engine', 'jade');
      app.use(express.favicon());
      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
      app.use(express.json());
      app.use(express.urlencoded());
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(express.cookieParser(crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')));
      app.use(express.session());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(require('stylus').middleware(APP_ROOT + 'public'));
      app.use(express["static"](APP_ROOT + 'public'));
      if (ENV === 'development') {
        app.use(express.errorHandler());
      }
      return app;
    };
    return ExpressConfig;
  })();
  module.exports = ExpressConfig;
}).call(this);

//# sourceMappingURL=express-config.map
```

- I can verify that the configuration is run before the catch-all route definition, as I have checked it by logging in each place to check the order.
- I can also verify that the assets configuration works when the catch-all route is removed.

Comment: Make sure the line to declare the static middleware is *before* this route.

Comment: The Express static configuration *is* run before the custom route is defined.

Comment: Could you post the code where the static middleware is defined?

Comment: Static middleware must be listed before app.use(app.router);

Comment: @HectorCorrea Thank you! I didn't even pay attention to that line. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static middleware should appear before app.router and the specific route.

```
// first
app.use(express["static"](APP_ROOT + 'public'));

// second
app.use(app.router);

// last
app.get('/*',whatever);
```