# Express routing - all routes allowed not working

Tags: node.js, express, routes, vue.js

I'm building a Vuejs app in a express server.
I want to display my app for all routes, then I will manage those routes in my Vue app router.

If I defined a unique route like `/home` my Vue app is well displayed, but when I define the router as `/*` to allowing all routes, the render doesn't work

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res) { 
    return res.render("application")
});
```

> app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

**application.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="public/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is because of the `app.js` read as the `application.html` file (weird). But if I define a unique route (ex : `/home`)  the content of the `app.js`is correct and my app works.

just in case : **app.js**

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express(),
    router = express.Router(),
    mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express') 

app.use(router)
app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());          
app.set('view engine', 'html');               
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

router.get('/*', function (req, res) {  
     return res.render("application");
});

app.listen(9000)
module.exports = app;
```

**UPDATE**
As @rsp said, the problem comes from the included script (`app.js`) in my html file, because it's also match the the `/*` route

The new updated problem is now :  how to have an exception just for those 'public' file in routes?

Comment: The solution to that updated problem is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764155/serve-assets-before-other-routes

Answer (score 1):

After looking into it in more details I can say that it doesn't look like a Node error, which would be something like this if you had a `"<"` in the first line of `app.js`:

```
$ node app.js 
/tmp/node-test/app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

and not just:

```
app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

as you wrote, which looks like a **browser** error instead. Do you have an `app.js` in your HTML that has HTML instead of JavaScript as its contents?

## Update

I think what is wrong is that your HTML tries to load a JS file but it gets the same HTML as the content of the JS file because that's what you're sending for every request, including any scripts potentially referenced in your application.html.

Instead of:

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res) { 
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/application.html')
});
```

Try using a static file sending from that directory:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
```

and access /application.html in your browser.

It may not work if you have any other routes in your app but you din't say that so it's hard to speculate. Also if you showed exactly the link that you want to access you page from - like http://localhost:3000/something - it would be easier to know what you're trying to do.

See also [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603778/webcam-doesnt-display-when-node-js-its-running/37603885#37603885) that I posted few hours ago that had a similar problem. Basically if you send the same file for every request then you will also sent the same file for any request for additional scripts, images etc. that are referenced in your original HTML file. You need to make sure that you are sending the correct assets in that case and express.static does that for you.

## Update 2

Now that you finally posted the entire `app.js` I see what's wrong.

Try changing it to:

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use('/', express.static('views'));

app.listen(9000)
module.exports = app;
```

Or if you can move the static files around you can make it simpler:

Try changing it to:

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.listen(9000)
module.exports = app;
```

and then move your html file to public and change this:

```
<script src="public/app.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

## Advice

Don't name two files `app.js` because when you get the error you get confused. In the first version in your answer you showed an error about `app.js` browser code referenced in HTML but showed the code of the Node code also named `app.js` but a different file.

Comment: good idea...but I have the same problem. I was inspired by this project https://github.com/jackhutu/jackblog-vue/blob/master/server.js...

Comment: Ok I commented my "<!-- <script src="public/app.js"></script>" and it's work. The probleme come from my generated js file. Sorry. (It's not me who "down vote" your post, sorry :-( )

Comment: I wrote an update and at the same time you wrote your second comment. It seems like what your're saying is what I expected - a browser error and not a Node error. Getting downvoted is always a risk of trying to help, I guess.

Comment: for your last updated message: yes the console displayed my app.js file with the content of my .html file (throwing that error). But in my project the file is correct and when my route is the '/home', everything work.

Comment: @DamienRomito Have you tried setting the route to /* but accessing it in your browser as /home maybe? Is it the same error as accessing it as / or different error or maybe it's ok in that case?

Comment: Strange. To sum it up: route '/home' is ok but route '/*' is not. What about routes '/' or '/home*' or '/home/*' ?

Comment: "/home*" works with an url like "/hometest", "/home/*" not work with an url like "/home/test" (same SyntaxError)

Comment: @DamienRomito I added an update to the answer. It would help if you paste an exact URL that you want to use in your browser and say if you have any other routes in your app.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! all my routes redirect to my application.html, even my public/app.js...

Comment: @DamienRomito My last update should fix the problem. Is it ok now?

Comment: But `app.use('/', express.static('views'))` not allow to respond to the url "/home" by exemple. (Moreover i'm using mustache as render engine ... i cannot display just an html page)

Comment: @DamienRomito I don't see mustache in your code and you didn't say you use it. You also didn't post any specific URL that you want to work so it's impossible to post a solution that would work for your case if you are not specific from the beginning.

Comment: The solution was here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764155/serve-assets-before-other-routes
Thank you for your time @rsp

Answer (score 0):

try using for get method

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) { ... });
```

or use this for all methods

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) { ... });
```